# Installing python modules in vs code not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, discord.py, praw

i am trying to install some module like: "praw" and "discord" but after using this command: `pip install praw` in vs code's terminal and after when i run the file, i got a error saying that `No module named 'praw'` i have searched the entire internet that how to install a module in vs code and about this error. pls help if you know.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't really matter what terminal you install in, vscode just makes a new terminal instance of whatever would be on your system (including the option between a command prompt or powershell on windows), and pip will install modules to the same spot regardless. Question for clarification- do you have multiple versions of python installed such that one pip may be installing to the modules location of the wrong python instance?

Comment: Please run `pip -V` and `python -V` and make sure the versions match

Comment: thanks for your help but i got to know that two versions of python were installed so i just changed the python interpreter of vs code and now everything is right !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have python3 you could try `py -3 -m pip install praw` or `python3 -m pip install praw`

edit: If this doesn't works in vscode then try running cmd as admin.